# Calculate price and display on woocommerce product single page under price (simple price, variable price)

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, hooks

I am planing to show a new price on my woo-commerce product page for all products. This is the installment price per month. I need to show this below the normal price (variable price and simple price) something like this.

0% interest installments starting from Rs.3,093

where Rs.3,093 is the new price.

this is the calculation i tried on W3 schools, and i got the calculation correct.

whereas 60000 is the price of the product multiplied by this number 5.15464 divided by 100

answer is 3,093 (answer should be rounded off to the nearest integer)

I need a custom function for this where i can add to my functions.php

```
<script>var x = myFunction(60000, 5.15464, 100); function myFunction(a, b, c) { return Math.round (a * b / c);}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to add JavsScript in functions.phhp is to put the JavaScript into a JS file an enqueue it. With `wp_enqueue_script()`.

js/mynicecode.js

```
var x = myFunction(60000, 5.15464, 100); function myFunction(a, b, c) { return Math.round (a * b / c);
```

in functions.php

```
function my_load_scripts($hook) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mynicecode_js', plugins_url( 'js/mynicecode.js', __FILE__ ), array());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. so the 60000 is an example i gave which is the first array. The value should be taken from the woo-commerce product price. which is $price and show it on (woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button).

so the js should be something like this **myFunction($price, 5.15464, 100);**

Answer (score 0):

[image: My product page should look like this]

the price shown in Red should be calcutated using the actual product price and the formulas i have given and display it like the way i have shown on the image.